# ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow_backend' from 'keras.backend

Tags: python, nlp

Я решил посмотреть на реализацию нейронной сети в чатах и попытался запустить код на своем компьютере, но, к сожалению, ничего не произошло... Вот вывод консоли:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\Voice_ChatBot\bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    from text_to_text import TextToText
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\Voice_ChatBot\text_to_text.py", line 24, in <module>
    from seq2seq.models import AttentionSeq2Seq
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\seq2seq-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\seq2seq\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\seq2seq-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\seq2seq\cells.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\engine.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\backend\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\recurrentshop-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\recurrentshop\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow_backend' from 'keras.backend' (C:\Users\akkenrl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py)
```

Репозиторий, из которого я клонировал код: https://github.com/Desklop/Voice_ChatBot

Заранее спасибо =)

Comment: Там упоминается Python 3.5-3.6, репозиторий 4 года не менялся. А вы на Python 3.11 запускаете. Наверняка с тех пор библиотеки сильно поменялись.